# How to open a webpage according to what user selects in dropdown and enter number in textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying design a main page in which user select an item from dropdown and input number to open a specific webpage. Is it possible to do in HTML5 only or i have to use Javascript. In either case could someone tell how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript.

```js
(function() {
  const urls = [
    'https://twitter.com',
    'https://facebook.com'
  ];

  document.getElementById('select-control').addEventListener('change', event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    // window.location = urls[event.target.value];
  }, false);
}());
```

```html
<select id="select-control">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```